# Link to cutil in GPU Computing SDK

Tags: gcc, compilation, cuda, nvcc

I've been trying to link to the functions in the cutil.h ofthe GPU Computing SDK released by NVIDIA.

At the moment, I am simply trying to compile this simple piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cutil.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned int time_total;    
    cutCreateTimer(&time_total);
    return 0;
}
```

using the following command:

```
nvcc -I/home/sj755/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/ -L/home/sj755/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib/libcutil_x86_64.a cutiltest.cu
```

Only to get the following error:

```
/tmp/tmpxft_000077cc_00000000-13_cutiltest.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_000077cc_00000000-1_cutiltest.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to 

`cutCreateTimer'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

ld also can't find -lcutil if I were to add the flag.
There is a static library that I'm supposed to link to, but for some reason this never works out. Here's what I tried:

1. I've changed my .bashrc file so that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the path to the static library

   ##########< CULA >

   export CULA_ROOT=/usr/local/cula

   export CULA_INC_PATH=$CULA_ROOT/include

   export CULA_BIN_PATH_32=$CULA_ROOT/bin

   export CULA_BIN_PATH_64=$CULA_ROOT/bin64

   export CULA_LIB_PATH_32=$CULA_ROOT/lib

   export CULA_LIB_PATH_64=$CULA_ROOT/lib64

   ##########< CUDA >

   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/cuda/lib64

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CULA_LIB_PATH_64

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/libnvvp/

   export CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR=/home/sj755/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR/lib
2. I've also tried renaming `libcutil_x86_64.a` to `libcutil.a`, still nothing.
3. Tried extracting the archive, creating a shared object file, and linking to it:

   ar -x libcutil_x86_64.a

   gcc -I /usr/include/GL/ -L /usr/include/GL/ -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXmu -lXi -lm -lpthread -shared *.cpp.o -o libcutil.so

   nvcc -lcutil -I /home/sj755/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/ -L /home/sj755/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib/libcutil.so cutiltest.cu

Only to get the following `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcutil`

What step am I forgetting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compilation statement is incorrect. It should look something like this:

```
nvcc -I$SDKROOT/C/common/inc -L$SDKROOT/C/lib cutiltest.cc -lcutil_x86_64
```

where SDKROOT holds the root path to the SDK, which looks to be

```
/home/sj755/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK
```

in your case. The key things to note here are that the library must be passed by name as a `-l` option *after* the code and objects that require it. A concrete example on OS X using your code snippet:

```
$ cat cutiltest.cc 

#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cutil.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned int time_total;    
    cutCreateTimer(&time_total);
    return 0;
}


$ nvcc -I/Developer/GPU\ Computing/C/common/inc -L /Developer/GPU\ Computing/C/lib -o cutiltest cutiltest.cc -lcutil_i386


$ ls -l cutiltest
-rwxr-xr-x  1 talonmies  talonmies  117548 May 25 07:57 cutiltest
```

But as a last remark, you really should rethink your choice of using the SDK cutils library at all. It is only intended for use with the SDK examples. It isn't part of CUDA, it has no documentation, it isn't guaranteed to work or not contain bugs, and isn't guaranteed to be consistent (or even present) from one SDK release to another.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! Thanks. I should tell you, I'm not using it as a choice. I'm working with a third-party library that uses it for some reason. I  have no option but to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not only your problem. Are you tried to link with cutil as with shared library? This solution was posted on [NVIDIA dev. zone forum](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=45494)